# How can I receive push notifications after converting pwa to apk?

Tags: notifications, apk, progressive-web-apps, push, service-worker

I have a web project.
Manifest settings have been completed, and service worker settings have also been completed.
So, the push comes normally on the web.

However, I wanted to release it on the Play Store for better accessibility.

So I used https://www.pwabuilder.com/ to get the apk.
However, push notifications do not come from this apk.

(All the apps I'm talking about are not apps downloaded from a website as a PWA, but apps created as an APK from the pwabuilder site and then downloaded.)

I created a button to request notification permission and tested it, but it did not work properly in the app.

const requestNotificationPermission = () => {
if ('Notification' in window) {

```
  Notification.requestPermission().then((permission) => {
    if (permission === 'granted') {

      navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then((registration) => {
        registration.showNotification('push title', {
          body: 'Push body',
          icon: '/img/pwa/icons/manifest-icon-512.png',
        });
      });
    }
  });
} else {
  console.error('Notifications API is not supported');
}
```

};

What I'm curious about is when the apk is created through PWA,

1. How can I request notification permission for an app? (This is not a request for notification permission from the web.)
2. I don’t know why push notifications aren’t going out. Please let me know if there are any keywords or sites that are helpful.
3. If you allow notifications in your browser, you will receive push notifications.
   However, if you allow notifications from the PWA app, but block notifications from the site in the browser app, push notifications will not arrive regardless of the action in the PWA. Is this normal?